# It is correct to state that $\partial f=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

I have the custom to write the total derivative of $f$ just as $\partial f$. Here $\partial f$ is the linear function $\partial f(v)$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(v+h)-f(v)-\partial f(v)h\|}{\|h\|}=0\tag1$$

for a vector $v$ (this is the definition that I know about total derivative of a function).

Let a function $f$ defined through the three variables $t,x,y$, such that $x$ and $y$ depends on $t$. Also suppose that the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous, hence we have that

$$\partial f(t,x,y)=\partial_t f(t,x,y)+\partial_x f(t,x,y)+\partial_y f(t,x,y)\tag2$$

My question is: it is the same $\partial f$ and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt }f$? If not, what is the difference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first line, do you mean total derivative or total differential?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I mean what is defined by (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total derivative $\frac{df}{dt}$is *only defined* for a function of one variable. If we have a function $f(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ of many variables, then we can define a total derivative of $f$ only if each of the variables $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ depends on some parameter $t$, say $x_{i} = x_{i}(t)$. In
this case,

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(x_{1}(t),...,x_{n}(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}\dot{x_{1}} + \ldots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}\dot{x_{n}}$$

What you call $\partial f$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. It can be identified with the row vector
$$\partial f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}, \ldots ,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}\right)$$

In the case that the coordinates $x_{i}$ are considered to all depend on some parameter $t$, we obtain the vector $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \left(\dot{x_{1}},\ldots \dot{x_{n}}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, by the chain rule, we have 
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(x_{1}(t),...,x_{n}(t)) = \partial f (\dot{\mathbf{x}})$$
Does that make sense?

**edit: response to comments**
In my opinion, the way to avoid being confused about this sort of thing is to be absolutely clear about exactly what function you are talking about. Suppose I have $f: \mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb {R}^m$ (the most general case). There are two kinds of derivative we can define:

1. What I just call "the derivative": the unique linear map $A_{x}:\mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb {R}^m$ (if one exists) such that
   $$\frac {f(x+h)-f (x)-A_{x}(h)}{||h||} \to 0$$
   as $h \to 0$, where $h $ is a vector in $\mathbb {R}^n $
2. The partial derivative with respect to argument $i $, which is a vector in $\mathbb {R}^m $, defined by only changing the $i^{th} $ argument:
   $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f (x+t\mathbf {e_{i}})}{t}$$ 
   where $\mathbf{e}_{i}=(0,...,1,...,0) $ is the $i^{th} $ basis vector in $\mathbb {R}^n $, and $t$ is a real number.

I don't like the Leibniz notation in this context because in some sense the independent variables "don't exist" and the operation of differentiating a function only depends on the function. For example when I wrote $\frac {df}{dt} $ earlier, what that really means is we chose some curve $\gamma(t) $ in $\mathbb {R}^n $, and differentiated the composition $f \circ \gamma $

Comment: this is not what Ive learned in multivariable calculus and what is wrote in many books... I think we have different definitions or something. Above $v=(t,x,y)$ is a vector. In a vector non necessarily each coordinate is dependent of each other.

Comment: I think we mean different things by total derivative. If you ignore the first line then the rest of the answer is certainly true.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I will read it carefully.

Comment: Idk if open a different question or not but... do you know some textbook where this distinction is exposed clearly? The two or three books that I have read about multivariable calculus define the total derivative as the linear map, what is a source of confusion. Maybe I must call it Fréchet derivative instead of total derivative to evade confusion (Im referring to the linear map)?

Comment: I'm not sure about where you can find this all clearly written in one place (I accumulated it from a long time taking physics and analysis classes in parallel). As for notation, the notations $D_{x}(f)$ and $D_{i}(f) $ for the "total" and "partial" derivatives of $f$ are the notations I've seen in analysis, while in physics the total derivative is rarely used (except in the context of Jacobians, where it is given the symbol $J $), while partial derivatives are given the leibniz notation you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are totally correct. The two symbols bear the same meaning.

But this equation that you wrote above,

$$\partial f(t,x,y)=\partial_t f(t,x,y)+\partial_x f(t,x,y)+\partial_y f(t,x,y)$$

is not exactly correct. It should be revised, since the total derivative is with respect to $t$.

$$\partial f(t,x,y)=\partial_t f(t,x,y)+\partial_x f(t,x,y) \dot x+\partial_y f(t,x,y) \dot y$$

Comment: I see what is my source of confusion. Thank you very much.